# How to create filenames with incremental numeric suffix

Tags: bash, shell-script, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm writing a shell script that automatically starts two scripts in order to record data for a research project I'm working on, and then when they are ended, it automatically creates a directory for the data and moves the data into the directory. The program creates a folder called "trials" (if one doesn't already exist) and checks in the trials folder for a folder named "trial$n", where n is an incrementing integer starting at 0. The idea is to make the name of the folder that is created increment by 1 every time the program is run. The entire program works fine except for the naming system. When I first wrote the code, it would work fine, but when I deleted folders "trial0...trial2", then next folder to be created would be "folder3", regardless of whether folders for trials 0 through 2 exist. This continued until folder "trial13" was created, and now the program simply overwrites "trial13" every time. Here's my code, the pertinent lines are 149:187

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3 #The purpose of this script it to automate and streamline the data collection
  4 #and analysis process for the touchless respitatory monitor. The script will
  5 #prompt you for the paths of the themral camera executable
  6 #(seek_viewer, usually in the libseek-thermal library), the path of the
  7 #main python script (SingleThreadedFaceDetectionV6), and the path of
  8 #removable media to which the files will be saved. It will then give you
  9 #command prompts to guide you through the process and put a fully-formatted
 10 #data folder in the removable media such that the folder is immediately
 11 #compatable with the MATLAB script on PC.
 12 
 13 #NOTE: Sometimes the thermal camera won't initialize properly and the program
 14 #needs to be restarted until it works.
 15 
 16 #Author:    Caleb Schreier
 17 #Date:      7 June 2022
 18 #OS:        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
 19 #Kernel:    Linux 5.10.103-v7l+
 20 #Architecture:  arm
 21 #Python:    3.7
 22 #Numpy:     1.22.4
 23 #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 24 
 25 #Import Settings
 26 source launcherSettings.txt
 27 
 28 #If setting don't exist, prompt user for settings
 29 if [ "$remember" != "y" ];
 30 then
 31 
 32 echo
 33 echo Please format paths as /folder/.../targetfolder
 34 echo
 35 echo Specify path to folder containing Thermal Camera Executable
 36 echo \(libseek_viewer\)
 37 echo
 38 
 39 read -r thermalPath
 40 
 41 echo
 42 echo Specify path to folder containing Python Script 
 43 echo \(SingleThreadedFaceDetectionV6\)
 44 echo
 45 
 46 read -r opticalPath
 47 
 48 echo
 49 echo Specify path to which data should be saved
 50 echo for flash drive, use /media/pi/DRIVENAME
 51 echo
 52 
 53 read -r mediaPath
 54 
 55 echo
 56 read -r -p "remember these settings? [y/n] " remember
 57 echo
 58 
 59 #Write settings to launcherSettings.txt
 60 case "$remember" in
 61     [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
 62         echo Saving to file...
 63         echo "remember=y" | sudo tee launcherSettings.txt
 64                 echo "opticalPath=$opticalPath" | sudo tee -a launcherSettings.txt
 65                 echo "thermalPath=$thermalPath" | sudo tee -a launcherSettings.txt 
 66                 echo "mediaPath=$mediaPath" | sudo tee -a launcherSettings.txt
 67 
 68         ;;
 69     *)
 70         echo "remember=n" | sudo tee launcherSettings.txt
 71         echo Settings not remembered.
 72         ;;
 73 esac
 74 
 75 else
 76 
 77 #if settings already exist, ask user whether to keep them. if not, reprompt for new settings
 78 echo
 79 read -r -p "Keep stored settings? [y/n] " modify
 80 
 81 if [ "$modify" != "y" ];
 82 then
 83 
 84 echo
 85 echo Please format paths as /folder/.../targetfolder
 86 echo
 87 echo Specify path to folder containing Thermal Camera Executable
 88 echo \(libseek_viewer\)
 89 echo
 90 
 91 read -r thermalPath
 92 
 93 echo
 94 echo Specify path to folder containing Python Script
 95 echo \(SingleThreadedFaceDetectionV6\)
 96 echo
 97 
 98 read -r opticalPath
 99 
100 echo
101 echo Specify path to which data should be saved
102 echo for flash drive, use /media/pi/DRIVENAME
103 echo
104 
105 read -r mediaPath
106 
107 echo
108 read -r -p "remember these settings? [y/n] " remember
109 echo
110 
111 case "$remember" in
112         [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
113         echo Saving to file...
114                 echo "remember=y" | sudo tee launcherSettings.txt
115                 echo "opticalPath=$opticalPath" | sudo tee -a launcherSettings.txt
116                 echo "thermalPath=$thermalPath" | sudo tee -a launcherSettings.txt
117                 echo "mediaPath=$mediaPath" | sudo tee -a launcherSettings.txt
118                 ;;
119         *)
120         echo "remember=n" | sudo tee launcherSettings.txt
121                 echo Settings not remembered.
122                 ;;
123 esac
124 
125 
126 fi
127 fi
128 
129 #initiate thermal camera
130 echo
131 echo Beginning thermal camera...
132 echo
133 
134 x-terminal-emulator -e "cd $thermalPath; ./seek_viewer -m[file]"
135 
136 #Initiate script for optical camera and analysis. Both this and the thermal camera
137 #program can be ended with CTRL + C
138 echo Beginning Python Script...
139 echo
140 echo Use CTRL + C to end script
141 echo
142 
143 python $opticalPath/SingleThreadedFaceDetectionV6.py
144 
145 wait
146 
147 echo creating file structure...
148 
149 sudo mkdir -v -p $mediaPath/trials
150 
151 #make numbered trial folder at the smallest unused number
152 echo testing for unused directory name...
153 
154 n=0
155 found=0
156 
157 while [ $found -eq 0 ];
158 do
159     if test -d "$mediapath/trials/trial$n";
160 
161     then
162 
163         echo Folder \"trial$n\" is taken.
164 
165         ((n+=1))
166 
167     else 
168 
169         echo found free space at folder $n
170             #make subdirectories
171             sudo mkdir -v -p $mediaPath/trials/trial$n/Thermal
172         sudo mkdir -v -p $mediaPath/trials/trial$n/Optical
173             #move photos and trial data to respective directories (may take a while)
174         echo moving thermal photos...
175             sudo mv -i $thermalPath/*.jpeg $mediaPath/trials/trial$n/Thermal
176             sudo mv -i $thermalPath/oldImages/*.jpeg $mediaPath/trials/trial$n/Thermal
177         echo moving optical photos...
178             sudo mv -i $opticalPath/*.jpeg $mediaPath/trials/trial$n/Optical
179             echo moving metadata...
180             sudo mv -i $opticalPath/avgValues.txt $mediaPath/trials/trial$n
181             echo move complete. Rerun launcher.sh to take another trial or eject media to run MATLAB code on PC
182 
183         found=1
184 
185     fi
186 
187 done
188 
189 echo Filing data from trial under folder \"$mediapath/trials/trial$n\"
```

Comment: Hi Caleb:  **1)** If you must refer to lines in a script you post, please include line numbering in your posted code. **2)**  In order to get attention, and to make your problem more easily accessible to potential helpers, please do not post the whole script if it is long (and/or full of boiler plate instructions, blank lines and/or comments), only post the pertinent section of it after isolating the issue). This will definitely speed up things fo you in terms of responses.

Comment: Comments: quote your variables by default ---- line 157: `while (( found == 0 )): do ... done`  -----  line 171 on: try writing `"${n}"` instead of just `$n`.  But there is nothing obviously wrong in mentioned section.

Comment: Line 159: `if test -d "$mediapath/trials/trial$n";` you misspellt variable `$mediaPath`. using a small case "P" (which is why I prefer to use minuscules for all variables that are not meant to be or to become environment variables!)  ;-)

Comment: I would write the loop as `n=0; while [[ -d "/path/dir$n" ]]; do n=$((n+1)); done` and do the rest of the work outside the loop. But I don't see anything wrong in the script you show, and it doesn't look like there'd be anything that would make 13 special, or that you'd have anything that you'd have anything resembling permanent storage that could cause it to skip the first ones after they're deleted. Just double-check to make sure all the paths are correct. You could run the script with command tracing on, either put `set -x` at the start, or run it with `bash -x script.sh`.

Comment: @Cbhihe's comment has a point, you're using `$mediapath` where the test happens, and `$mediaPath` everywhere else. But that means the tested path isn't even created ever, so it should find `$mediapath/trials/trial0` every time. Unless you had an earlier version of the script that did create _that_ path. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) would warn about unassigned variables like that, and using `set -u` would make them errors.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: As `$mediaPath` is not defined, did you look into the `/trials` directory if any subdirs exist there?

Comment: @Cbhihe "_please include line numbering in your posted code_" - please don't. It makes it impossible to copy and paste without having to edit the original code.

Comment: @roaima: the solution is (for instance) one short `ed` one-liner away if you use `vi` or `vim`, i.e. `s/^\s*[0-9]*\s//` in command mode... Only **with** line-numbering will a reader be able to identify the section that OP tentatively identifies as the probable culprit without either counting lines on screen or copying / pasting and setting numbering on in your favorite editor's session... So as far as I am concerned we can agree on the fact that OP is badly formulated per my first comment, but as I said in that case line-numbering is the least bad solution for this question to become readable.

Answer (score 1):

Drop this example snippet into a file, and repeatedly run it. Delete an earlier directory and that earlier one will be reused the next time this is run.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
base='trials'     # Base directory where everything lives
prefix='trial'    # Prefix of subdirectory name
n=0               # Starting suffix number

mkdir -p "$base"
while [ -d "$base/$prefix$n" ]; do ((n++)); done

echo "Will create and use $base/$prefix$n"
mkdir "$base/$prefix$n"
```

Notice that the created directories will not list in ascending numerical order. If you had an upper bound on the number of directories you could pad the number with leading zeroes (eg 0004 instead of 4).

In your production code, don't forget to double-quote your variables like I have done here. This prevents the shell trying to expand them into separate words.

Comment: @CalebSchreier: Please see this short [FAQ item](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good answers like this one can be rewarded with a green check mark in the left margin.